# How can I retrieve array data by id to multiple checkbox in Laravel 9

Tags: arrays, laravel, checkbox, roles

This is my Controller function:

```
public function get_edit_user ($id) {

    $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();

    return view('adminpanel.user.edituser', compact('user'));

}
```

And this is my Blade view:

```
  <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Roles</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label">

                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="role[]"
                    value="{{$user->id}}" {{ $user->role == ["SuperAdmin"] ? 'checked' : '' }}  >
                 Super Admin
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
   

               <div class="col-sm-3">
                   <div class="form-check">
                       <label class="form-check-label">
                         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="role[]"  
                        value="{{$user->id}}" {{ $user->role == ["Admin"] ? 'checked' : '' }} >
                   Admin
                       </label>
                     </div>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-3">
                   <div class="form-check">
                       <label class="form-check-label">
                         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="role[]" 
                         value="{{$user->id}}" {{ $user->role == ["User"] ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                        User
                       </label>
                     </div>
               </div>


           </div>
         </div>
                        
     </div>
```

if the user has one role for example SuperAdmin it can retrieve it. But when user has multiple role like SuperAdmin and User it does not retrive any of it.I am trying to retrieve them to checkboxes.

The data storing inside database as array ex: ["SuperAdmin","Admin","User"]. I can store data easyly but when you try to retrieve it by id i got this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Don't store an array of strings as a representation of a Role system. Use a proper `roles` table, and a pivot between `users` and `roles`, and associate them properly. Read the docs for a proper Many-to-many relationship (a User can have Many Roles, a Role can have Many Users): https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Thank you for answer.I used to that separete roles table before and I wanted to try something different. I can return these datas from array for example  if (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->role== ["SuperAdmin"]) endif. The problem occur when I try to edit users by $id and try to fetch these tree roles at the same time.

Comment: I think you may want to change `value="{{$user->id}}"` with `value="User"`, `value="Admin"`... Which will allow you to get the result via `request('role')`

Answer (score 0):

By your question, I am guessing you are having trouble getting data from the database that is stored in an array format (or what looks like one). your condition should be:

```
  in_array("SuperAdmin",  $user->role) ? 'checked' : ''
```

Use it like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="role[]"
                    value="{{$user->id}}" {{ in_array("SuperAdmin", $array) ? 'checked' : '' }}  >
```

Comment: The thing is I can retrieve the data from array db column but when I try to retrieve multiple of them from one id it does not work. For example I can retrieve user role to the blade if user has one role is shows perfectly. But when user has multiple roles this condition check does not show anything.

Comment: have you tried what I suggested? if you can get the db column then your problem is only how to use that data. are you asking how you can check if multiple values are in an array or not?

Comment: I can use data with no problem. But when I trying to add multiple checkbox on the blade for example there is 3 checkbox when the user has multiple role like Admin and SuperAdmin. Checkbox could not retrieve data for these checkbox. I tried to fetch data in the <h5> tags if its working its working correctly. My main problem is multiple checkbox retrieve data. Thanks advance.

Comment: ok, I edited my answer. try to use that and see if it helps. If not, add a comment detailing what issue you faced.